# Is tuple pattern matching with atoms a good idea in erlang?

Tags: erlang

I'm a bit of a newbie to Erlang, and I've been reading some documentation that claims that atoms are not garbage collected.  That's all well and good, but then that opens up a bigger question: is it a good idea to use them as "tuple labels" for pattern matching?  If I have a relatively heavily-used Erlang app, and a function like this:

```
-module(geometry).
-export([area/1]).
area({rectangle, Width, Ht}) -> Width * Ht;
area({square, X}) -> X * X;
area({circle, R}) -> 3.14159 * R * R.
```

will this risk crashing my VM? If the `area` function is run three million times, wouldn't that crash my Erlang VM since rectangle, square, and circle are atoms?

Comment: Example code copied from https://pragprog.com/articles/erlang

Comment: Nope. Totally normal way to do things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you aren't creating atoms dynamically this isn't an issue, because the compiler/VM will use the same atom object internally to represent all uses of the atom `rectangle` -- there is only ever one `rectangle`, `circle` etc. atom in use.

The exception to this rule is when you create an atom dynamically using the `list_to_atom/1` function to create atoms from lists/strings.  This is generally considered a super bad idea.

Comment: I feel slightly silly for not figuring this out myself, but I suppose we all have to start somewhere.  Thanks for the help!